# Python Creating lists of lists

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have 3 lists examples below, I want to match each one and create new lists

```
l1 = [a,b,c]
l2= [1,2,3]
l3=[7,8,9]
```

How do I create 3 new lists with expected output:

```
l1 = [a,1,7]
l2= [b,2,8]
l3=[c,3,9]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` or a comprehension:

```
# Create a list of lists
ls = [l1, l2, l3]

ls = list(zip(*ls))  # output: a list of tuples

# OR

ls = [l for l in zip(*ls)]  # output: a list of lists
```

Output:

```
>>> ls[0]
['a', 1, 7]

>>> ls[1]
['b', 2, 8]

>>> ls[2]
['c', 3, 9]
```

Comment: but I have a lot of lists 20+ this was just a simple way to show my question. Got a method for when you cant list all l1, l2, l3?

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?